# How can I force my D5100's shutter to stay open?

Tags: nikon-d5100, shutter, shutter-release

I have a Nikon D5100 and a MC-DC2 remote. I'd like to use the remote to hold the shutter open until I release the button, however I don't see an option for this. Is this something that I can do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is called "Bulb Mode".

On most DSLRs (including the D5100), you would change to shutter priority or manual mode and slide the shutter speed larger until it reads "Bulb" or something of the sort.

Comment: Ah. I wouldn't have ever associated "bulb mode" with this functionality. It works perfectly!

Comment: @ThomasOwens -- the "bulb" in this case is the thing you squeeze on an old-style pneumatic shutter release. The name may not make as much sense in this age of electric/electronic everything, but there are still cameras/shutters that use the old-style release. Cameras may also have a "T" (time) mode, where one click opens the shutter and the next closes it, which is a lot more comfortable than holding a button for *very* long exposures.